# mySQL DB adding table while site is active

Tags: mysql

it's been a while since i've used a mySQL DB, is it ok to create a new DB table, while the site is active or should i take the site down for maintenance before hand?

-thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `CREATE` syntax is fine on a live database, just don't run something like `DROP` or `TRUNCATE`.

- [CREATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

If you're worried about harming your database, take a backup;

```
mysqldump -u root -p <database_name> > backup.sql
```

Alternatively, you can [create a new user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html) with just the CREATE privilege.